# How can i attach className to projected content?

Tags: angular

I have `app-form` component and inside i projected input.

```
<app-form>
   <input />
</app-form>
```

i wonder, how can i attach dunamically className to the input in the `app-form` component ?

So

```
 ngAfterContentInit() {
  // find input and attach className - and at the end i will have
  // class="someClassName"
}
```

note: i know that i can do this throught directive

```
 @HostBinding('class')
  elementClass = `someClassName`;
```

but i need to to this from the `parent component - PROJECTOR`

Answer (score 0):

where projected give a ref like below :-

```
<abc>
   <projected #myref></projected>
</abc>
```

in the component where its projected do,

```
@ContentChild('myref', {read: ElementRef})
set child(myChild: ElementRef) {
   if (myChild) {
        myChild.nativeElement.classList.add('someClassName');
   }
}
```

Comment: but on this way - if in `<projected> i get multiple elements - input and paragraph - the class will be applied on the both elements right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngClass` for that :

```html
<app-form>
   <input [ngClass]="myVar" />
</app-form>
```

and in your controller:

```
export class MyComponent {
  public myVar = "whatever-you-want"
}
```

`[ngClass]="myVar"` will evaluate the value of `myVar` in your controller, and pass the class accordingly. You can then change the value to whatever suits you from the controller